# How to catch or log memory deallocation errors?

Tags: c++, windows

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        auto b = malloc(69);
        free(b);
        free(b);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
    }
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}
```

It will never print "Hello, world!" because the exception that `free` causes the second time it is called, is not catchable. A similar thing can happen with `operator delete` in C++.

Now, I don't want to *catch* these errors, per-se, but not even `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` gets me a call. My program just dies and I have no logging to work with; my only hope of finding these kinds of bugs is attaching a debugger hoping I can reproduce whatever happened.

So, is there anything I can do within my program to get a notification similar to what the debugger seems to be getting?

Comment: Do you want these programming errors to be a part of the product or do you want them eradicated before you release this? I assume you want to fix the programming errors. Using a debugger, tests and memory sanitizers etc is one way to go.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The errors wouldn't be an intentional part of the product, but the error handling for it would be; so when the user has a crash, they will have some crash log to give to me, as opposed to nothing.

Comment: @Sainan A double-`free` (or double-`delete`) is not guaranteed to raise an exception at all, it might just corrupt memory instead. Certainly not a C++ exception, anyway. Maybe an OS exception, though (like `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`, etc).  Try using ["Structured Exception Handling"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp?view=msvc-160) via a [`__try/__except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/try-except-statement?view=msvc-160) to catch it.

Comment: I see. This is often where "monitor" applications take place. A well tested application that monitors another.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am already using SEH, but neither my __try..__except nor unhandled exception filter got a notification.

Comment: @Sainan Then it is not actually throwing any kind of exception to begin with, C++ or SEH or otherwise.

Comment: @Sainan Memory management errors don't (necessarily) throw exceptions. It's just Undefined Behavior. It is a fatal and unrecoverable error to double free, you can't catch it and correct it after the fact.

Comment: Yes, that is my problem, I would like to at least get a notification so I know what happened, other than "the program crashed."

Comment: @Sainan If you can't catch it, you can't notify on it. You will likely need a separate watchdog process monitoring to detect when your main process terminates unexpectedly. Or, at least setup Windows to handle the crash to generate a WER notification and minidump log for you.

Comment: Operating systems have their own idea of what an "exception" is, and it has nothing to do with C++ exceptions.

Comment: FWIW, if you start using RAII types like `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, `std::any_standard_container`, then you don't even have to worry about this anymore.  Manually memory management should really not be used if at all possible.

Comment: @NathanOliver I get that, but as I said, `operator delete` can produce the same issue, only there it's harder to reproduce and 1 abstraction away. 

Comment: @Sainan I'm not saying to use `delete`, in fact, you shouldn't.  What you should use are types that do, but do so in a safe manner, i.e, follow the rule of 0/3/5.  Lets say you need to allocate a `Foo`, that doesn't need to be shared with anything.  Instead of `malloc` or `new`, use `auto ptr = std::make_unique<Foo>(constrcutor_parameters);`.  Now, `ptr` is an object with automatic storage duration, so it's guaranteed to be destroyed at scope exit and the destructor of `ptr` will properly delete the memory.

Comment: This means there is no longer a need to call anything, you just let the scope end, and the memory goes with it.

Comment: And I am saying that the code that these abstractions give you can still have an error while deallocating their memory.

Comment: @RemyLebeau WER looked interesting, so I tried creating an exception handler DLL, but it also doesn't seem to get any calls.

Comment: No, that is wrong. You will not ever be able to double-free a `std::unique_ptr`, for example. That's built into the type system. Once you stop calling `new` and `delete`, you will no longer have to deal with double-free bugs. They simply no longer exist. There is literally no reason at all to ever call `delete` in C++ (since C++11).

Comment: I am using C++20 and I have had crashes on `operator delete` within standard library code. It is inevitable given enough stupidity of the programmer.  Anyway, I can deal with errors being inevitable, but I really dislike not getting any logging from crash. 

Comment: I will question whether it is possible to write a program using Standard Library collections and smart pointer types exclusively with no calls to `delete`, and have it fail due to a double-free bug. Regardless, the easiest way to solve this is to let the system [collect a user-mode dump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps) for you.